# React-redux make a sync callback

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

i have this code:

```
that.props.getChats(that.props.state.chatModule.login.body.agent[0].company_id, that.props.state.chatModule.sessions.chatHashesChoosed)
            that.scrollChatToBottom(sessionHash)
```

that.props.getChats is a function creator which use async ajax call.
i want that.scrollChatToBottom to run only after the ajax call return. the thing is that because i use this function creator, i dont get any promise or someting...

i dont want to make the call inside the component.

Comment: I'd like to see your whole component, but my initial recommendation would be to make the scrollChatToBottom method call inside the success function of your ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

I guess getChats will retrieve some data and update the app state, which then trigger your component to be re-rendered according to the newly retrieved data? If so, you can trigger scrollChatToBottom in *componentDidUpdate*, e.g.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (this.props.chatData !== NULL) { // assuming chatData is the data retrieved by getChats
        // Do scrollChatToBottom here
    }
}
```